# Sequence term and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

1. Generate the first five terms of the sequence given as 4n - 3
2. Find the tenth term of each of these sequences :
   A) 7n +1
   B) 10 - 2n
   C) n squared - 3n

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Your post would be easier to read if you used [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Here you replaced the value of n with 1,2,3,4 and 5

So the first 5 terms would be 1,5,9,13,17

For the second question you have to put n=10 for each one.

So a) $$7*10+1 = 71 $$
b)$$10-2*10=-10$$
c) $$10^2-3*10=70$$